# How to validate an array with WTForms and flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a custom form which submits an array:

```
<form method="post" action="/doit">
    <input type="text" name="mylist" value="one">
    <input type="text" name="mylist" value="two">
    <input type="text" name="mylist" value="three">
    <input type="text" name="mylist" value="four">
</form>
```

How do I build a WTForm so that `mylist` requires at least one item when validating the form?

Comment: Can you post the Form code? Are you using a `FieldList` field?

Answer (score 3):

By reading the source code, I got the answer!!

the **Form** side:

```
class MyListForm(Form):
    mylist = FieldList(StringField(validators=[]), validators=[])
```

ok..the important and confusing thing is that how to post data, here is  the answer:

**your data should be like this(python dict)**

```
{'mylist-0': ['one'], 'mylist-1': ['two'], 'mylist-2': ['three']}
```

All the **Fields** have a function process() to get itself's data. Normal classes (eg, StringField, FloatField) implement from **Field**, **FieldList** has it's own process() function, cause it needs to iterate its fields, it got a 
***_extract_indices()***  function to extract indices while iteracting, that is the point, check the [source code](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms%2Ffields%2Fcore.py#L894):

```
def _extract_indices(self, prefix, formdata):
    """
    Yield indices of any keys with given prefix.

    formdata must be an object which will produce keys when iterated.  For
    example, if field 'foo' contains keys 'foo-0-bar', 'foo-1-baz', then
    the numbers 0 and 1 will be yielded, but not neccesarily in order.
    """
    offset = len(prefix) + 1
    for k in formdata:
        if k.startswith(prefix):
            k = k[offset:].split('-', 1)[0]
            if k.isdigit():
                yield int(k)
```

That is how it get its data !!!

it needs **the key to be like "foo-0"**, and the data must be **a list!**!!

I don't know why it's not mentioned in the [document](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList)...

My first answer here, wish it can help!!!     :)

Comment: Please consider leaving this type of question as comment since you are asking a question and not answering... :)